# Autocomplete in Pydev / Eclipse is not showing all methods

Tags: python, eclipse, autocomplete, pydev

I've been using Eclipse for many years now (for Java and Perl programming), but I've only recently installed PyDev as I want to use it as the IDE for learning Python.

My problem is that when I press the period sign after a variable name, the list of autocomplete suggestions does not show all the methods for that type.

E.g. In the screenshot below, I want to use the isoformat() method in the datetime module. If I manually type the variable.methodname i.e. end.isoformat(), the code is working fine.
However, while typing if I just press period after the variable End, the autocomplete suggestions dropdown does not contain isoformat anywhere. As you can see, datetime is in the list of Forced builtins, but that does not seem to help.

I have looked at other questions related to autocompletion problems for PyDev here on the site, but none of the solutions suggested in those threads are fixing my problem. As a beginner in Python, a working autocomplete would really be a lot of help for me. Can someone please help?

Details about my setup:

- Eclipse Version: Luna Release (4.4.0) Build id: 20140612-0600
- PyDev for Eclipse 3.7.1.201409021729
- Python 2.7.3
- Windows 8.1

Edit: Bah, StackOverflow won't let me post a screenshot image because this is a new account and I have less than "10 reputation". What does preventing me from communicating more clearly using screenshots, have to do with experience points? Not cool on their part.

Anyway, I've pasted my code below:

```
import  datetime


start = datetime.date(2014,7,7)
end = start + datetime.timedelta(days=180)
print(end.isoformat())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out the answer.

I think that due to the dynamic nature of Python, in the code snippet above, the code editor does not know what type of object will be stored in the variable 'end', and so it does not know that it will be a date object, and hence does not show 'isoformat()' in the autocomplete suggestions.

When I type the variable 'start' and then a period, it does know that it is a date object, and it does show 'isoformat()' in the autocomplete suggestions.

So the autocomplete is working after all! That's a relief. :)

Comment: Thank you Fabio, for confirming this. :)

Answer (score 0):

Only thing I can think of is - make sure that the interpreter you have is the same one you've got the modules installed under.

If you've verified that, you can always rescan the modules (takes a bit for it to build the index)

Comment: I only have one instance of Python installed on my machine, located at the path C:\Python27.

The settings in Eclipse are as follows:
 - Preferences > PyDev > Interpreters > PythonInterpreter is set to the value "C:\Python27\python.exe" under the key named "python"

- Project > Properties > PyDev Interpreter/Grammar > Interpreter is set to "python"

So they seem to be in sync. I also tried re-scanning the modules, but that made no difference.

Anyway, thank you for your response!

Comment: I can't even upvote your suggestion as I don't have "15 reputation". This site is really harsh on newcomers.

Comment: No worries. Since I didn't actually solve your problem I'd feel dishonest getting a +1 on my answer anyway. ;)

Answer (score 0):

i think you should try with Java 8 version. Crosscheck that the eclipse take java 8 version.Then only pydev u can view in eclipse .As pydev requires Java 8 versions in Eclipse Luna.

Comment: improve your question by adding some example, references